# When I tried to power up my Magikarp, the CP went down(!)

Tags: pokemon-go

Got a Magikarp the other day with 150CP and 39 HP. With 20/15 IV I thought it was an ok magikarp to evolve (I'm a collector, not a fighter..) But since I had some candy extra, I tought I'd like to power it up a bit first. When I power up, the CP went down from 150 to 132 and the HP down to 34. Surprised I powered it back up to 150, but now it only have a HP on 37. What just happened?

Comment: I think your problem was that you powered up a magikarp. But yeah, this already has an answer.